# Is the use of the word "that" in the sentence below correct?

Tags: word-usage, relative-pronouns

A light fall of ash, that it may destroy one year's crop, often pays the farmer well in future years with the fertility it adds to the soil.

Comment: That sentence would make perfect sense to me if "that" was replaced with "though." Where did you get the sentence from?

Comment: Sumelic, you are right. " Though" can work well here. The sentence appeared in a CAE cloze test. My friend used "that", but I was confused if it was correct or incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is not grammatical in current English.

In modern English, *that* may be used as a relative pronoun, so

> A light fall of ash, that may destroy one year's crop ...

(without the 'it') is fine.

But in the example as you give it, the subject *it* is expressed, so *that* is not a relative pronoun but a conjunction introducing a subordinate clause. In Early Modern English (the era of Shakespeare and the King James Bible), it could do so, with the sense *in order that*; but in current English *that* does not have that function.

Comment: Hmm... I thought *that* could only be used to introduce restrictive relative clauses. So if the comma is kept, wouldn't the relative pronoun *which* have to be used instead?

Comment: Some people claim that, @sumelic, but I don't think it's entirely correct. To me _that_ is preferable to _which_ here, but on reflection I think that it is a special sort of relative clause I hadn't been aware of before, that you might call an "explanatory" clause. It 's not restrictive, sure, but it is doing more than the customary "commenting" function of a non-restrictive clause: it is explaining why "a light fall of ash" might be of concern.

Comment: Colin Fine, l have learnt a new piece of information about using "that" as a conjunction.  Anyway thank you for this historical explanation, which I think is very plausible.

Answer (score 1):

I would edit such a sentence to read "... , despite that...", or "... given that ...", or "... even knowing that ...". I would certainly not publish it in its present incorrect form. Otherwise, Colin Fine's answer is good guidance for you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions . Your contrasting phrases are really excellent.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is not grammatically correct.  *That* is a [relative pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_pronoun), standing for "A light fall of ash".  Therefore, *that* serves as the subject of the relative clause that it introduces.  But you also have an *it* in that clause.  Having two subjects doesn't make sense; you would have to drop *it*.

Here is one corrected version:

> A light fall of ash, that may destroy one year's crop, often pays the farmer well in future years with the fertility it adds to the soil.

---

It's also possible that you were thinking of using another word there?

> A light fall of ash, **though** it may destroy one year's crop, often pays the farmer well in future years with the fertility it adds to the soil.

Comment: I think the last version with a concessive word is more perfect. Thanks.